# Multi DB test - Create a dynamic ChoiceField for admin interface?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am testing a multi-database setup and need to populate a ChoiceField in the admin interface. I need a pull down for the **movie_title** field in movies.MovieEvent populated from the **title** field of calendar_app.Event via the foreign key in calendar_app.EventOccurence.
With a foreign key in play [I can't make movie_title a foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations) to the EventOccurence model so I'm attempting to pull the records and then create a tuple to populate the pull down.

Here's what I have, this throws **ValueError, not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1):**

**These models are routed to database #1**:

```
# calendar_app/models.py
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    ...

class EventOccurence(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='event')
    event_date = models.DateField()
    ...
```

**This Model is routed to database #2:**

```
#movies/models.py
class MovieEvent(models.Model):
    movie_title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ...
```

**Admin:**

```
#admin.py
from calendar_app.models import EventOccurrence
...
class MovieEventAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    movie_events = EventOccurrence.objects.filter(Q(event__tags__slug__exact='movie')).distinct()
    y = ", (".join(str("'" + x.event.title + "', '" + x.event.title + "')") for x in movie_events)
    movie_choices = str("(" + "(" + y + ")")
    movie_title = forms.ChoiceField(choices=movie_choices)
    class Meta:
        model = MovieEvent
        fields = (
            ...
            'movie_title',
            ... 
        )


class MovieEventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        form = MovieEventAdminForm
```

The above throws the ValueError but when test my tuple creation it returns it just fine.

```
>>> movie_events = EventOccurrence.objects.filter(Q(event__tags__slug__exact='movie')).distinct()
>>> y = ", (".join(str("'" + x.event.title + "', '" + x.event.title + "')") for x in movie_events)
>>> movie_choices = str("(" + "(" + y + ")")
>>> print(movie_choices)
(('Halloween', 'Halloween'), ('Star Wars', 'Star Wars'), ('Chappie', 'Chappie'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. I did not know about ModelChoiceField which makes it very easy:

```
#admin.py
from calendar_app.models import EventOccurrence
...
class MovieEventAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    movie_title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= EventOccurrence.objects.filter(Q(event__tags__slug__exact='movie')).distinct())

    class Meta:
        model = MovieEvent
        fields = (
        ...
        'movie_title',
        ... 
    )


class MovieEventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MovieEventAdminForm
```